# iOS Arrays with custom classes to arrays with NSStrings

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I have my own class with several properties and I have them in NSArray. I need to use them for method which takes NSArray of strings. So I am asking what is best aproach to get array with strings from my array which has custom classes. I can create second array and use it but I think there could be better way. I need to have it for different custom classes (from one, I want to use for example name property to new NSArray, in second title property and so).

I hope I explained well but I tried it once more on example:

```
NSArray *arrayWitCustomClasses =  ... fill with custom classes;
// setValues method takes NSArray with NSStrings
// when arrayWithCustomClasses used it returns copyWithZone: error on custom class
[someObject setValues:[arrayWithCustomClasses toArrayWithStrings]];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as your object exposes the required values as `NSString` properties you can use the `valueForKey` method of `NSArray`.

For example

```
NSArray *arrayOfTitles=[arrayWithCustomClasses valueForKey:@"title"];

NSArray *arrayOfNames=[arrayWithCustomClasses valueForKey:@"name"];
```

Or

```
[someObject setValues:[arrayWithCustomClasses valueForKey:@"title"]];
```

and so on

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think you need to use `valueForKeyPath:` ?

Comment: valueForKey:
Returns an array containing the results of invoking valueForKey: using key on each of the array's objects.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. It's a little better then @Trenskow because I can use properties with valueForKey.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSMutableArray *strings = [NSMutableArray array];

for (NSObject *item in arrayWithCustomClasses) {
    /* You can use a different property as well. */
    [strings addObject:item.description];
}

[someObject setValues:strings.copy];
```

Answer (score 2):

Like @Tim says, but you could shorten it by just using:

```
[someObject setValues:[arrayWithCustomClasses valueForKey:@"description"]];
```

Same result. One line of code.

Then implement the `description` method of your custom classes to return whatever properties and formatting you want.